# Filling an int Array inside a Structure

Tags: c, arrays, struct, initialization, int

So, I was wondering about the initialization of Arrays inside of a struct. If I put this above main function:

```
typedef struct{
int day[7];
} WEEK;

void initTest(WEEK week, int seven) {
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<seven; i++){
        week.day[i] = i + 1;
  }
}
```

..seems not to work, by invoking it in main like this:

```
WEEK week;
initTest(week, 7);
```

I get some garbage values pulled from memory filled to my array.

However, if I use the following in the main function directly

```
int i;
for(i=0; i<7; i++){
        week.day[i] = i + 1;
}
```

..I get good filing of `Array (1.. to ..7)`.

> Can someone care to explain why this happens and maybe give some examples or alternatives how to fix this (with pointers/malloc or otherwise), etc?

Comment: What do you expect `void f(int i) {i = 5;} int main() {int x = 7; f(x); printf("%d\n", x); return 0;}` to print?

Comment: void does nothing (no return value), so main prints out 7!

btw. ive tried out filing structure members the way i first tried to fill an Array in a structure and it's somehow working:

    `typedef struct{
    int day;
    } WEEK;



    void initTest(WEEK week) {
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<7; i++){
        week[i].day = i + 1;
    }
    }`
..so basically defining an Array containing 7 structures in main,
 like: 

`WEEK week1[7]; initTest(week1)`

 works somehow different, because it fills values good ?

Comment: What about `int f(int i) {i = 5; return i;} int main() {int x = 7; f(x); printf("%d\n", x); return 0;}`?

Comment: the return value of function f is 5, but it does nothing to the Action. So 7 will be printed in the console. If we used `printf("%d\n", f(x));` the console Output would be 5.

Comment: As you can read in every good C book or tutorial, C is call-by-value.

Comment: Now you know why `void f(Week w) {w = ...stuff...;} int main() {Week w; f(w); print(w); return 0;}` doesn't print the stuff. It works the same for Weeks as it does for ints. (Arrays work differently, for IMO silly reasons)

Comment: i get the Basics like.. `int f(int * i) {*i = 5; return whatever;}
int main() {int x = 7; f(&x); printf("%d\n", x); return 0;}` gives Output 5. I wanted to know the real difference, between Array and Struct. For filling an Array inside of a struct, we pass an adress (&) Argument to a function, in the Definition head of the function we use the scheme `DATATYPE * variablename`  and inside the Body of the function we use `(*week).day[i] = i + 1;` or equivalent `week->day[i] = i + 1;` So far i got that.

Answer (score 1):

`initTest()` received a copy of `week`.  The calling function's `week` is not changed.  Instead have the calling code and receiving code use a pointer to `week`.

```
void initTest(WEEK *week, int seven){
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<seven; i++){
        week->day[i] = i + 1;  // ->
  }
}

WEEK week;
initTest(&week, 7);  // &week
```

Answer (score 1):

Modifying arguments in a function won't affect what the caller passed.

Use pointers to modify caller's local variable.

```
void initTest(WEEK *week){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<7; i++){
        week->day[i] = i + 1;
    }
}

WEEK week;
initTest(&week);
```

I removed the argument `seven` because it seamed meaningless.